# Why do the Qt programs in the virtual machine quit as soon as it is run?

Tags: qt, crash, qt5, virtual-machine

I've built a 64-bit program, using VS2017 and Qt 5.12.0, in Win7 SP1, and it ran without problems. I copied it to VMware whose operating system is also 64-bit Win7 SP1, when I ran it I got an error—'This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.'

I searched on the Internet for this error, then I copied the folder 'D:\Qt\Qt5.12.0\5.12.0\msvc2017_64\plugins' to VMware in the same path of the program.

And then I ran the program in VMware again, its progress just started but quitted immediately, and without showing any errors.

I copied another Qt program which is of another project to the VMware, it behaved the same.

So how should I check the problem when this program even can't keep running and doesn't report any error messages?

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Please run you code under a debugger.  That should at least provide some clues.

Comment: Have a look at windeployqt

Comment: @G.M. You're right, G.M.! Thank you very much! I built a debug version and run it again, the error had come out—'Could not find QtWebEngineProcessd.exe'. And the problem had been solved!

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Oh, I think this is a good way, too! Thanks a lot, Frank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed G.M.'s suggestion, built a debug version and ran it again, I finally saw the cause of the problem——'Could not find QtWebEngineProcessd.exe'.